# Why am I getting a 'type mismatch' error?

Tags: excel, vba, paste, type-mismatch

I am trying to copy a range from one workbook to a table in another workbook to capture production data. I am able to copy the correct range and open the workbook with the table successfully. However, when it tries to paste the information into the next available row in the table I get the error 13. I am rather new to vba and can't seem to find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim wbTime As Workbook
   Set wbTime = ThisWorkbook

   Dim wbData As Workbook

   Dim N As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   Dim UsdRws As Long
   UsdRws = Cells.Find("*", After:=Range("A32"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

   wbTime.ActiveSheet.Range("A6:O" & UsdRws).Copy

   Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("S:\Lean Carrollton Initiative\Allen\Buffering Interrupters\1st Shift\B10\Data.xlsx")

   wbData.ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(Sheet1).Range(N & "A")

   wbData.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing error 13, specifically?

Comment: Probably the `Worksheets(Sheet1)` part?

Comment: @VincentG right, just repro'd. Thought it was funny because `Worksheet` has no default member, so `Debug.Print Sheet1` throws error 438 for that reason - error 13 makes sense since it's then the `Worksheet` reference that's being passed to the `Worksheets` indexer, throwing a type mismatch - which confirms that `Sheet1` is the sheet's code name, because that would be error 9 / subscript out of range if it was a `Variant/Empty` undeclared variable. In other words, `Sheet1.Range(...)` fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range needs to be for correct syntax

```
Range("A" & N)
```

You could also use

```
Cells(N, "A")
```

And `sheet1` should be `"Sheet1"` i.e. `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. `Sheet1` by itself, unquoted, will be seen as a variable. Unless you have a string variable by that name? Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to check for variable declarations.

---

Additional comment from @MathieuGuidon:

*I'll add that Sheet1 is the default code name of the "Sheet1" worksheet in a new workbook; it's a project-scoped identifier VBA creates for free, giving you a compile-time reference to that specific Worksheet object - thus, retrieving that object from the Worksheets collection is redundant altogether: Sheet1.Range(...) would be preferable -- and ideally, that sheet's (Name) property should be modified to a meaningful identifier, e.g. SummarySheet, which makes SummarySheet.Range(...) legal, without needing to declare any SummarySheet variable*

Comment: I'll add that `Sheet1` is the default *code name* of the "Sheet1" worksheet in a new workbook; it's a project-scoped identifier VBA creates for free, giving you a compile-time reference to that specific `Worksheet` object - thus, retrieving that object from the `Worksheets` collection is redundant altogether: `Sheet1.Range(...)` would be preferable -- and ideally, that sheet's `(Name)` property should be modified to a meaningful identifier, e.g. `SummarySheet`, which makes `SummarySheet.Range(...)` legal, without needing to declare any `SummarySheet` variable.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I will never explain things as well as you. Do you mind if I copy pasta, and attribute, your comment?

Comment: The thing is, `Sheet1.Range("42N")` throws error 1004, not 13. I'm not sure where the error is occurring in OP's code, but it has to be before that well spotted bug.

Comment: I personally don't like using the code name of the sheets, sometimes users plays with worksheets and copy/paste/rename them and that can break code easily. It's easy to tell them "rename the worksheet" than "Open the VBE, look for the worksheet object, change the Name property".

Comment: @VincentG care to explain? Using the code name is *precisely* the only thing that prevents a user from breaking your code by merely moving or renaming a sheet, short of enabling workbook structure protection.

Comment: I agree it doesn't occurs often, and that I could probably prevent it by protecting the sheets, but we had some case where user made a "work copy" of a worksheet, put modification in it and then delete the original and rename the copy. If you do so, the code name is lost.

Comment: haha yeah, users deleting worksheets is indeed a problem... the `Workbook.SheetBeforeDelete` event should probably be handled to prevent that ;-) (although, it can't be cancelled so the proper handling would be... a msgbox saying "I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave", followed by the workbook closing without saving.

Comment: users are always a problem ;)

Comment: I got the data to copy and paste into the correct workbook. Thank you for the help! However, I have encountered another problem....haha...Instead of pasting on the next available row in the table is is jumping down 28 rows and then pasting...

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Destination1:=Worksheets(Sheet1).Range(N & "A")
> ```

@QHarr [correctly identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54330677/1188513) the problem with `Range(N & "A")`, and proposed a fix for the type mismatch error you're getting at `Worksheets(Sheet1)`.

I just wanted to explain what's going on in more details than can fit a little comment box.

`Sheet1` is an implicitly declared object variable of type `Worksheet`, whose compile-time identifier is determined by the `(Name)` property of the worksheet:

[image: Sheet1 properties toolwindow showing the (Name) property]

If you change this property value to, say, `SummarySheet`, then `Sheet1` is no longer a valid identifier, and `SummarySheet` becomes one - and this is part of why specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of every module is important, because without it VBA will happily compile and run, except now instead of `Sheet1` being illegal, it's now an undefined `Variant/Empty` value that can merrily passed around accidentally, which can make things very hard to debug (the same holds true for *any* undeclared variable, not just worksheet code names).

So `Sheet1` is a `Worksheet` object reference. If `Worksheet` had a *default member* that returned the value of its `Name` property, your code would work.

But `Worksheet` doesn't have a *default member*, so `Worksheets(Sheet1)` is passing the `Worksheet` object reference as an argument to the `Worksheets.Item` indexer (implicitly - because the `Worksheets` class *does* have a default member, its `Item` property), which is expecting a `Variant` holding either the name of a worksheet (`Variant/String`), or a numeric index (`Variant/Integer` or `Variant/Long`).

Passing a `Worksheet` object to `Worksheets.Item` is what's throwing the *type mismatch* error.

Therefore, assuming that `Sheet1` worksheet is the intended destination, this would fix it (making abstraction of the `Range` parameter bug identified earlier by QHarr):

```
wbData.ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheet1.Range(...)
```

There is never a need to retrieve a worksheet that exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, from the `Worksheets` collection.

Note that in the original code:

> ```
> Destination1:=Worksheets(Sheet1).Range(N & "A")
> ```

Since `Worksheets` isn't qualified, the `Workbook` it belongs to is ambiguous: if that code is written in `ThisWorkbook`, then `Worksheets` is a member call against `Me`, i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`. Otherwise, it "conveniently" implicitly refers to *whatever workbook happens to be currently active*, and that's often a risky assumption for code to be making.